# Can I prevent accidental overwrite of local variables in TypeScript / JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, local-variables

Today I wasted an hour debugging a trivial issue, where a local variable named `server` was being initialized and configured - then, on one of the last lines in the same file, accidentally it was being redeclared, e.g. by another `var server = ...` statement, effectively creating a *new* variable named `server`, thus causing the previous variable to fall out of scope; yet, because these were the same type of variable, with the same name, everything else continued to work, making this fairly hard to debug.

Is there a TypeScript or JavaScript language feature, that prevents this sort of thing?

My thinking is that, declaring two variables with the same name, in the same scope, ought not to be allowed at all.

Perhaps there's a linter or some quality assurance tool that has the ability to check for and prevent this sort of thing? (and perhaps other "bad" patterns?)

Comment: Use strict like you should be anyway. Also, Jslint.

Comment: Technically it wasn't the `var` part of the stray statement that caused your problem, it was the initialization expression. All `var` declarations are *hoisted* to the top of the function anyway, so redundant declarations are not a problem. It's the *assignment* that overwrote the variable's previous value.

Comment: *"by another var server = ... statement, effectively creating a new variable named server"* Not in JavaScript (I can't speak for typescript). In JavaScript, if it's the same scope, the `var` part of that was a complete no-op; it was just an assigment expression.

Comment: @Nit: Strict mode doesn't turn redundant declarations into errors. Unfortunately. Nor does JSLint warn you of them.

Comment: I checked this in the online version but neither jsHint nor Lint complained about the double declaration... Totally expected them to complain with default settings though.

Comment: @Jonathan: So did I. :-) Strict mode I knew didn't, but I assumed either JSLint or JSHint (or both) would and was very surprised. I couldn't even find an option on JSHint to do it (JSHint having a lot more options than JSLint).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder found it: `"shadow"        : true,     // true: Allows re-define variables later in code e.g. var x=1; x=2;` This default is useful for for loops which begin with `var i = 0`

Comment: @Jonathan: That's how I read it too (well, `shadow: inner` I think it would be). **But** even if I explicitly turn that on, the online version still doesn't complain about a redundant declaration in the same scope. (I tried `true`, `false`, `inner`, and `outer` just in case I was completely misunderstanding.)

Comment: "*…declaring two variables with the same name, in the same scope, ought not to be allowed at all*". It is allowed because it has no effect, the second declaration is ignored (see [*ECMA–262 §10.5 Declaration Binding Instantiation step 8*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.5)). Declarations are processed before **any** code in the same scope is executed, therefore you can't have two instances of the same variable attached to the same execution context.

Comment: @RobG `the second declaration is ignored` Nah...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Depends on what software you use, I suppose, does for me.

Comment: @Jonathan: RobG's correct, the second declaration is ignored. The **assignment**, on the other hand, isn't.

Comment: Ok, thanks for clearing that up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two options:

1. Use ECMA Script 6 and `let`.
2. Use [jslint](http://jslint.com/) with `var`.

[There is a closed issue about this on the GitHub/Microsoft/Typescript](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/656) page. The recommendation is to target ECMA Script 6 and use `let`.

## ECMA Script 6 with `let`

[In ECMA Script 6 this would create an error](http://www.es6fiddle.net/i8uq6hz5/):

```
let x = "foo";
let x = "bar"; // TypeScript with ECMA 6 will complain here
console.log(x);
```

> Duplicate declaration, x

## JSLint with `var`

Also, [though the following won't throw a TypeScript error](http://www.es6fiddle.net/i8uqsiak/), the [jslint](http://jslint.com/) tool will complain about it, even if you aren't using strict.

```
(function () {

    var x, y;
    x = "foo";
    y = "foo";

    function sayMsg() {
        // jslint will complain here
        var y = "bar";
    }

    sayMsg();

    // jslint will also complain here
    var x = "bar" + y;

}());
```

This is what [jslint](http://jslint.com/) will tell you:

> Redefinition of 'y' from line 3.
>
> Combine this with the previous 'var' statement.

Comment: I thought I had seen `let` used in this way in other languages, but had not seen anything to suggest it would work that way in JS. Great news! Thanks :-)

Answer (score 6):

Use `let` everywhere possible.

A `let` variable cannot be used before its declaration:

```
var x = 3;
function f() {
  console.log(x); // ReferenceError, x is not defined
  let x = 5;
}
```

Comment: It's correct to say to use `let`, but the example isn't that pertinent to OP's situation because using `var` in the example would not change the value of the first `x`. I think in OPs case he means a situation where "the variable is in the same scope", such as `var server = ...; var server = ...` (no error). This can result in an error if using `let` instead—`Cannot redeclare blocked-scoped variable`—which would be desired.

Comment: Yes, correct - the issue was with variables in the same scope. I should have posted a code sample. +1 for the answer, but marking Shaun's answer as accepted because it was more complete.